# How can i use Log4Net in F#?

Tags: .net, f#, log4net

How can i use Log4Net in F#? i execute this program but nothing happened.
i install log4net(version is 2.0.12) on nuget.

here is my config file

```
    <log4net>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="LogFiles/"/>　
    <staticLogFileName value="false"/>
    <appendToFile value="true"/>
    <rollingStyle value="Date"/>
    <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd.lo\g"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%-5p %date{yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %-20c{1} %-20M %m%n" />
    </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
    <level value="ALL"/>
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
    </root>
    </log4net>
```

and my program.fs

```
    open System
    open log4net
    open log4net.Config

    let from whom =
      sprintf "from %s" whom

    [<EntryPoint>]
      let main argv =
      let message = from "F#" 

      let log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType)

      log.Info("Hello logging world!")

      printfn "Hello world %s" message
      0
```

Comment: i suggest to configure log4net with code instead of the config file.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .NET Core, you have to tell log4net to load the config at the start of your program, like this:

```ml
open System.IO

FileInfo("log4net.config")
    |> XmlConfigurator.Configure
    |> ignore
```

More details [here](https://stackify.com/making-log4net-net-core-work/).